# What are consequences of forming clusters on variables that are not normally distributed?

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, clustering, skewness, dbscan

I am trying to use DBSCAN to obtain clusters of chess player rating changes (Elo rank) over one year of games.

I have a bunch of input variables, some of which are not normally distributed even if I try and transform them using non-linear functions (e.g. log) or algorithms.

[image]

**If the variables are not normally distributed won't DBSCAN be biased to form clusters that do not discriminate variation that is typical?** e.g. if there is extreme skew then the tails will unevenly influence cluster formation with other other variables.

**The authors of the following two articles, imply that a normal distribution may result in clusters that discriminate values better.**

1. *"Normality is not a requirement for Clustering algorithms
   **however a normal distribution of the data can help achieve better results since outliers might skew the cluster centroids.**""** [Link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/clustering-countries-using-unsupervised-machine-learning-denegri/)*
2. ***In some scenarios, you may also want to apply transformations    to the distribution.** E.g., the distance to the nearest MRT looks    similar to log distribution, meaning that most houses are located    close to the station with few further away.Therefore, **if you were    more interested in differentiating between all the houses close to    the MRT [a log-distributed value] and were less interested in the ones further away, then you    could apply log transformation to spread them out**.**" [Link](https://towardsdatascience.com/dbscan-clustering-algorithm-how-to-build-powerful-density-based-models-21d9961c4cec)*

**Are these authors mistaken?**

Note that total game count in my dataset is probably not normally distributed, because I decided to only players which played 100 games (this decision was made to include players who know the rules)

However, there are other variables (e.g. time between consecutive games) which are not normally distributed and I have no explanation.

Note: "bin" (see top right panel) refers to the percentile of the player's performance (i.e. a player which plays 1000 games in one year has 10 games per percentile, whereas a player which plays 100 games has only 1 game per percentile).

Comment: why do they have to be normal?

Comment: DBSCAN makes no assumptions about distributions. Look at [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN#/media/File:DBSCAN-density-data.svg) from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN).

Comment: It seems you will generate clusters not just of rating changes but of a wide set of input variables.

Comment: Not only does DBSCAN not assume normality, in fact no clustering method I'm aware of does. In fact associating clusters with modes, in data with the nicest possible clusterings variables are usually multimodally distributed, i.e., non-normal. Even Gaussian model-based clustering only assumes normality *within* clusters but not overall. Arguably, if all variables look perfectly normal, this looks like *no* clusters exist (we can't be sure but...).

Comment: @ChristianHennig I've read two articles where the authors suggested to transform the data for certain variables to have them approximate normal distributions; the post has been edited to include their justification. Can you elaborate why they may be mistaken?

Comment: @TunaFishLies The second article doesn't say anything about normality as far as I can see, and the first one is littered with misunderstandings. For sure having a normal distribution and not having outliers are not the same thing.

Comment: It's also wrong to claim that data are normally distributed if the (absolute) skew values are low as the author does. In fact you can have outliers together with low skew values. In any case there's no reason to believe that low skew values are helpful or even necessary for clustering.